# Query results not expected in a Union

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have this query that retrieves me quantities for some products for the current week and last week. I want this quantites to be related to the respective week, not the cumulative.

```
SELECT 'Last Week' AS Last_week, 
SUM( CASE WHEN week IN ( 1 ) THEN tinta ELSE 0 END ) AS last_week_tinta, 
SUM( CASE WHEN week IN ( 1 ) THEN semi ELSE 0 END ) AS last_week_semi, 
SUM( CASE WHEN week IN ( 1 ) THEN so_pure ELSE 0 END ) AS last_week_so_pure 
FROM wp_8_bi_helper_custom t 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM wp_8_bi_helper_custom t2 WHERE t2.person = t.person AND t2.week = t.week AND t2.iteration > t.iteration )

UNION ALL 

SELECT 'Current Week' AS Current_Week, 
SUM( CASE WHEN week IN ( 2 ) THEN tinta ELSE 0 END ) AS tinta, 
SUM( CASE WHEN week IN ( 2 ) THEN semi ELSE 0 END ) AS semi, 
SUM( CASE WHEN week IN ( 2 ) THEN so_pure ELSE 0 END ) AS so_pure 
FROM wp_11_bi_helper_custom t 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM wp_8_bi_helper_custom t2 WHERE t2.person = t.person AND t2.week = t.week AND t2.iteration > t.iteration )
```

However, results for last week are correct but for current week are not.

I'm getting this result

```
Last_week    last_week_tinta     last_week_semi    last_week_so_pure
Last Week    2                   1                 3
Current Week 13                  3                 1
```

When I should be getting

```
Last_week    last_week_tinta     last_week_semi    last_week_so_pure
Last Week    2                   1                 3
Current Week 0                   0                 1
```

The first column is just for labeling purposes but needs to be there.
I'm not that expert in SQL so any help is appreciated.

Comment: without knowing the data in the table you are selecting from, the queries help very little. can you create a sqlfiddle? althought, i did notice in the first `WHERE NOT EXISTS` you use a self-join on `8`, however the second query is driven by `11` and you still use `8`. is this intended, or should it be another self-join?

Comment: No need. I spoted the error. The second query is getting data from a different table! ^^ geez.... thanks anyway @PlantTheIdea
EDIT: you spotted the same thing as well. Guess I was posting at the same time :) Place formal answer if you want